# TypeORM leftjoin with same column name

Tags: mysql, typeorm

## Environment

1. TypeORM
2. Typescript
3. Express
4. MySQL 5.7

## 'TeamSpeed' Table in MySQL DataBase

| team | go | right | left |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 40 | 60 | 120 |
| 2 | 50 | 40 | 70 |
| 3 | 35 | 10 | 80 |
| 4 | 70 | 15 | 97 |

## 'TeamWords' Table in MySQL DataBase

| team | go | right | left |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "go1" | "ok right" | "left1" |
| 2 | "lets go" | "right2" | "left2" |
| 3 | "here we go" | "right3" | "left100" |
| 4 | "move" | "right4" | "OK LEFT" |

## TypeORM Entities

```
@Entity('team_speeds')
class Speeds extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  team: number

  @Column()
  go: number

  @Column()
  right: number

  @Column()
  left: number
}


@Entity('team_words')
class Words extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  team: number

  @Column()
  go: string

  @Column()
  right: string

  @Column()
  left: string
}
```

## Problem

I know that how to join two table in MySQL Query.

But, I don't know how to join two table in TypeORM.

How to join two table based on team column ?

Comment: Can you share your entity classes?

Comment: @ErangaHeshan I edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the entity classes like below:

```js
@Entity('team_speeds')
class Speeds extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  team: number

  @Column()
  go: number

  @Column()
  right: number

  @Column()
  left: number

  @OneToOne(() => Words, words => words.Speeds)
  words: Words;
}


@Entity('team_words')
class Words extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  team: number

  @Column()
  go: string

  @Column()
  right: string

  @Column()
  left: string

  @OneToOne(() => Speeds, speeds => speeds.words)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'team' })
  speeds: Speeds;
}
```

Then when you want to query data, you can use one from below.

#### 1. Using find:

```js
async foo(teamSpeedId: number) {
  const speeds = await getManager().getRepository(Speeds).find({
    relations: ['words'],
    where: { team: teamSpeedId },
  });
}
```

#### 2. Using QueryBuilder:

```js
async foo(teamSpeedId: number) {
  const speeds = await connection
    .getRepository(Speeds)
    .createQueryBuilder("speed")
    .leftJoinAndSelect("speed.words", "word")
    .where('team = :id', {id: teamSpeedId})
    .getMany();
}
```

Check [this documentation](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/one-to-one-relations.md) for more info.